# Выборка фамилий из базы по условию

Tags: sql-server

Добрый день!

Задача такая:

Есть список фамилий: "**Ив**ан**ов**", "**Ив**аницкий", "**Ив**анк**ов**"

Нужно  составить условие, нечто на подобии LIKE и вида  "Ив*ов" выдало бы "Иванов" и "Иванков". Это можно как-то транслировать на T-SQL ?

Спасибо!

Comment: Вам чем-то условие `like 'Ив%ов'` не подошло или я не совсем понял Ваш вопрос?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE users.lastName LIKE "Ив%ов"
```